# Can I rename SQL Azure Database Name?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

How can i rename the database in sql Azure?
I am trying `Alter database old_name {MODIFY NAME = new_name}`
but not work.
rename is available in Azure or not?

Comment: use link I will give you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/rename-a-database?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/rename-a-database?view=sql-server-2017#rename-a-database-using-transact-sql

> ALTER DATABASE MyTestDatabase MODIFY NAME = MyTestDatabaseCopy ;

You can change the name, there are also some pre-reqs

**Limitations and Restrictions**

- System databases cannot be renamed.
- The database name cannot be changed while other users are accessing the database.
- In Azure SQL Database, you must make sure no other users have an open connection to the database to be renamed.